# strange char when use Python to convert from excel .xlsx to csv file

Tags: python, excel, csv

i used this to line of code
to convert **excel** file with **xlsx** extension to **csv** file
but when i have arabic char in **excel** file i got strange char like

Ø´ÙŠÙ… Ù„Ø§Ù„Ù†Ù‡Ø¶Ù‡ Ù„Ù„Ø§Ø³ØªØ«Ù…Ø§Ø± Ø°ªØ«Ù…Ø§Ø± Ø

```
data_xls = pd.read_excel(newFilename +'.xlsx' , dtype=str , index_col=None)

data_xls.to_csv('CSV ' +newFilename+'.csv', encoding='UTF-8' , index=False , header=True)
```

any help please ?

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution and I did it with a small change in my code. I replaced `encode='utf-8'` with `encode='utf-8-sig'` and it works for me.

My new code:

```py
data_xls = pd.read_excel(excelfilename+'.xlsx' , dtype=str , index_col=None)
data_xls.to_csv(newFilename+'.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig' , index=False , header=True)
```